# Error on converting dense matrix to sparse matrix of size 27 GB

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am trying to convert a large matrix of size 27 GB to a sparse matrix using the method,

```
sparse_matrix<-as(dense_matrix,"dgCMatrix")
```

Then it shows the following error,

```
Error in .Call(dense_to_Csparse, from) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed,
```

How can i solve it.

Comment: I don't typically deal with these kinds of things but the help file https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dgCMatrix-class.html seems to indicate a different way to convert to something of dgCMatrix.

Comment: I am looking for a method to convert large matrix that have more than `2^31` elements to **sparse** matrix ,don't want to create a new one

Comment: `more typically via as(*, "CsparseMatrix") or similar. Often however, more easily via Matrix(*, sparse = TRUE), or most efficiently via sparseMatrix().` was the part I was thinking might be more relevant.  Also your first code line says 'dense_matrix'. Is it actually dense? If so you aren't going to see gains by using a sparse matrix.